# How to get full request URL in Node.js running on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, https

I'm running a node application on heroku and I would like to find the full request URL through which my application is being requested. In particular, I want to know if it has been accessed through HTTP or HTTPS, so that I can redirect clients connecting through HTTP to use the same URL but with HTTPS instead.

Since the application is running under proxies, etc., the protocol and host portions of the requests I can read are the ones where node is running, as forwarded by Heroku infrastructure.

Hints appreciated!

BTW, my app uses requestjs, in case that is relevant

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186134/node-js-express-and-heroku-how-to-handle-http-and-https/16271205#16271205

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed to know. I wish I had found that instead of asking the question. req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] == "http" was the important bit for me.