# node js Hapi js and heroku how to handle https

Tags: node.js, heroku, hapi.js

I want to allow only https traffic to my Hapi Js server.

In this thread:
[Node.JS, Express and Heroku - how to handle HTTP and HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186134/node-js-express-and-heroku-how-to-handle-http-and-https)

it was accomplished by:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
        app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            res.setHeader('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=8640000; includeSubDomains');
            if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] && req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === "http") {
                return res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.host + req.url);
            } else {
                return next();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is hapi.js?  The use of `app.use`, `next` and `res.redirect` really makes this look like Express.

Comment: Oh, you're saying that this was an express solution you found and you would like a hapi solution?  What have you tried?  Have you reviewed the manual?

Comment: Also, having an `if` statement that explicitly does things differently in production versus anywhere else seems very scary.  How can you test it?  You could set NODE_ENV to `production` in a test environment, but then why do we call it `production`?  Maybe you want a `enforceSSL` setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good npm module for this: https://www.npmjs.org/package/hapi-require-https

Answer (score 0):

This is my (fairly hacky) solution:

```
// redirect all http request to secure route
if ('production' === process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  server.ext('onRequest', function (request, next) {
    if (request.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
      request.originalPath = request.path;
      request.setUrl('/redirect');
    }
    next();
  });

  server.route([{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/redirect',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
      var host = request.headers.host;
      reply().redirect('https://' + host + request.originalPath);
    }
  }]);
}
```

Maybe someone can come up with something cleaner.
Warning: This does not prevent insecure http traffic. It just redirects the browsers to https locations.